# jQuery - Open href from Popup

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, popup, click, href

his is my first question here, let's see how it goes.

So, here it goes:

HTML:

```
<td><a href="https://www.google.es" class="confirmDelete">delete</a></td>
<div id="confirmDeleteBox" title="Delete Confirm" style="display:none"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $('.confirmDelete').click(OpenDeleteDialog);
//Delete Column functionallity
function OpenDeleteDialog() {
    $("#confirmDeleteBox").html("Confirm Delete Dialog Box");

    $("#confirmDeleteBox").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Modal",
        height: 250,
        width: 400,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(true);
            },
            "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(false);
            }
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
}



function callback(value) {
    if (value) {
        $(this).closest('.confirmDelete').attr('href');

    } else {
        alert("Rejected");
    }
}
```

So, the thing is that I have a table with a column that deletes, copies or adds rows, and I want to make a popup confirmation each time you want to delete, copy or add. 
The popup works, but when I want to press "yes" it doesn't return to the link I pressed (in my example google link).

I am working with dynamic link, so I can't point directly, the rows (and it's href) are generated dynamicly.

How can I "click" the href of the link in the "yes" option of my popup?

Btw, I tried in this part:

```
function callback(value) {
    if (value) {
        $(this).attr('href');

    } else {
        alert("Rejected");
    }
}
```

I tried with: `$(this).attr('href');`  ,  `window.location = $(this).attr('href');`, etc...

Comment: do you want the link to be clicked on `Yes`?

Comment: Yes. Is a confirmation. When you click the "delete" link I want the popup to show and asking you "yes or "no" (that is working at the moment) and when you click "Yes" it gets the "href" value of the original link (the delete link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. In `callback()`, `this` is not what you think it is.
2. `.attr('something')` is a *getter*. It only retrieves a value.

Try this:

```
$('.confirmDelete').click(OpenDeleteDialog);
//Delete Column functionallity
function OpenDeleteDialog() {

    var $link = $(this); //keep track of the element that was clicked

    $("#confirmDeleteBox").html("Confirm Delete Dialog Box");

    $("#confirmDeleteBox").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Modal",
        height: 250,
        width: 400,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(true, $link); //pass the reference to the element
            },
            "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(false);
            }
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
}

function callback(confirmed, $el) {
    if (confirmed) {
        window.location = $el.attr('href'); //change the page's location    
    } else {
        alert("Rejected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very very much. Worked perfectly. I got it all wrong from the beginning. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ln7b/)

---

Try this,

```
$('.confirmDelete').click(OpenDeleteDialog);
//Delete Column functionallity
var currentHref;   //store href of current selected link

function callback(value) {
    if (value) {
        window.location = $(currentHref).attr('href');

    } else {
        alert("Rejected");
    }
}

function OpenDeleteDialog(event) {

    currentHref = event.target;  //get the clicked element

    $("#confirmDeleteBox").html("Confirm Delete Dialog Box");

    $("#confirmDeleteBox").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Modal",
        height: 250,
        width: 400,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(true);
            },
            "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(false);
            }
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

---

- Use `event.target` to get value of the current link.
- You can also pass the value of the current selected element using

  ```
  $('.confirmDelete').click(function(){
      OpenDeleteDialog(this);
  );

  function OpenDeleteDialog(obj){..}
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I put in the other one and worked out, didn't try yours because I am in a hurry (work, work, work) but I apretiate very much you attention and effort. Thank you very much!!! :D